# JQuery change value from radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a variable called `category` that must change its value according to the selected radio button. The problem is that I do not get that at the click of a radio button or another, the value will change instantly.

This is the code I have:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="category" value="doctor" /> Doctor
<input type="radio" name="category" value="police" checked /> Policia
</form>

var category = $('[name="category"]:checked').val();
```

I need you to automatically change the value of the variable `category` when you click the radio buttons.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to change the value of category every time a user changes the selected radio button. Therefore you will need an event to trigger when the user clicks on a radio. You can check out the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NATrU/)

```
var category = null;
$("input[name='category']").click(function() {
    category = this.value;
});
```

Comment: Nicely this works also if you change the selected radio using your keyboard's arrows

Answer (score 45):

Attach an event handler to the `change` event:

```
$(':radio[name="category"]').change(function() {
  var category = $(this).filter(':checked').val();
});
```

Comment: You want to use the `change` event like this answer says, not the `click` that some others are advising. Using `change` ensures you update your value even if the user navigates and selects the radio button using their keyboard.

Comment: @albanx: `click` will only fire if the button was clicked (even if it is disabled). `change` fire when the value is changed (regardless of the method, be it keyboard or mouse), which can't happen if it is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

```
var category;
    $(':radio[name="category"]').change(function() {
      category=this.value;
    });
```

And this is a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/1vxqrq53/) demo.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need simply something like this:

```
var category;

    $('radio[name="category"]').click(function(){
      category=this.value;
    });
```

Comment: I think it's better to use the "change" event, it's more general purpose than "click".

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't give the same ID for more than one element, you should use class instead like this :

```
<form>
  Option 1<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio" value="Option 1">
  Option 2<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio" value="Option 2">
</form>
```

instead of :

```
<form>
  Option 1<input type="radio" name="opt" id="radio" value="Option 1">
  Option 2<input type="radio" name="opt" id="radio" value="Option 2">
</form>
```

and your code still the same and it should work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `category` variable use `$('[name="category"]:checked').val()` wherever you want the value of the checked radio button. Otherwise you can make use of `change` or `click` event to set the `checked` radio buttons value into `category` variable.

Comment: This is a direct approach rather than implementing the `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

utilize the [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) in order to capture the change event for a radio button.